# Python Socket:Converting bytes object

Tags: python, sockets, byte

I received data via TCP socket, it should be `"12345678901"` as value. I tried also to convert it by `int.from_bytes` in `byteorder ='big'` and `'littel'`
,`struct.unpack`...

However it didn't work well.

Actual value I got is `b'\xd2\x04.\x16\xc5"'( << data == conn.recv(2048))`

Which kind of way should I use for converting it to integer?

EDIT: on Server side(really typical)

```
TCP_IP = '192.168.3.50'
TCP_PORT = 8000
BUFFER_SIZE = 2048  

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connection address:', addr)

data_dummy = 0

while 1:

data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
if not data: break
if data_dummy != data or data_dummy == 0:
    print("received data:", data)
    print("converted(big)", int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='big'))
    print("converted(little)", int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='little'))
```

on Client side(it is came from PLC)

I'll put command line.

```
NEXT>> 8
received data: b'\xd2\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00'
converted(big) 230914621702144
converted(little) 1234
```

It works, if is only 1234.

```
NEXT>> 9
received data: b'\xd2\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00'
converted(big) 230914638479360
converted(little) 66770
```

It doesn't work, in this case 12340001.

```
NEXT>> 11
received data: b'\xd2\x044\x12\x00\x00'
converted(big) 230915495297024
converted(little) 305398994
```

it doesn't work and structure itself is strange.

Comment: That depends upon how you sent it. How did you send that data?

Comment: What do you mean by "*didn't work well*"?

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant by using int.from_bytes, I'm getting completly wrong number like 38229876016338.I just need decimal conversion from it.

Comment: Problem is why 6byte date looks 4 byte and what is [x04.].

Comment: Can you put your send and receive fucntions

Comment: What is `int.from_bytes`? Please post all the code. Also do you have the code that sends the data? But note that in socket communications if the sender sends 3 bytes, it doesn't mean that the receiver would read each byte in in a separate `recv` call (3 of them). It could read all 3 bytes in a single call. Of course handling that 3 bytes of data would be wrong because the data is meaningless. I see *Python* code and *PLC* output, and both seem to **receive** data. Who **sends** it?

Comment: int.from_bytes is standard python function.https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: Reading all 6 bytes at the same time would be fine, if we could separate after python receive these value. In this case, im trying to send 6bytes of 3-word(1234,5678,9010).Where is the best timing to separte the value?Sender is PLC, receiver is socket made by Python program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the last comment cleared things up. You encoded that integer in 3 words (2 bytes each). Previously, I did some tests trying to "decode" the value as a 64bit `int` as *12345678901* (***0x2DFDC1C35***) doesn't fit in 32 bits, but (obviously) without success.

According to [[Python]: Format Characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters), for words we have the `short` correspondent (I chose the `unsigned` version: ***H***):

> ```
> >>> import sys
> >>> import struct
> >>> sys.version
> '3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'
> >>>
> >>> data = b'\xd2\x04.\x16\xc5"'
> >>> fmt = b"<HHH"
> >>> parts = struct.unpack(fmt, data[:6])
> >>> parts
> (1234, 5678, 8901)
> >>>
> >>> # If you want to combine the 3 numbers into the original one:
> ...
> >>> parts[0] * 100000000 + parts[1] * 10000 + parts[2]
> 123456788901
> ```